# Generating all sums of one element per line in a matrix in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, math

Let us say I have a matrix of 4 lines by 3 columns. E.g.:

```
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
 7  8  9
10 11 12
```

I would like to generate the list of all possible sums, a sum being computed by taking only 1 element per line, for each line. E.g.:

```
1 + 4 + 7 + 10 = 22
3 + 5 + 7 + 11 = 26
...
```

How could I do this in Python?

Comment: So it seems that you need the [cartesian product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) of the rows.

Comment: Do you know the general procedure?  i.e. could you do this with pencil and paper?

Comment: I could do it with a small matrice but I do not know the general procedure for this. I would prefer to do it in a way I can easily scale up the matrix size.

Comment: @Mat.R Are you familiar with writing recursive functions?

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: @user3386109 I used some when I learned programming. I never used them professionally.

Comment: What exactly will be the output? A list? With duplicates? like `res = map(sum, itertools.product(*matrix))`?

Comment: @trincot As mentioned, a list of sums. The duplicates are fine. I can handle this after.

Comment: So, is the above line what you need?

Comment: @KellyBundy My attempts are on a paper with simple matrices. I can easily do it with simple matrices but it quickly becomes difficult when I increase the number of lines and columns. I guess my problem is that I do not know how to translate to a generic solution in the code.

Comment: @trincot It might be. I am at the moment reading what bereal suggested about cartesian products. I need to try it first to see if it is what I need.

Comment: fyi, `itertools.product` *performs* a Cartesian product.

Comment: @trincot yes absolutely. It is mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Now I can put a name (cartesian product) on what I was searching for I can see it is a common question. It is probably a duplicate. Should I still let the title and explanation as it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a Cartesion product, summing the values in each result of that product. You can use `itertools`, as it provides an iterator over a Cartesion product:

```
import itertools

m=[[ 1,  2,  3],
   [ 4,  5,  6],
   [ 7,  8,  9],
   [10, 11, 12]]

res = map(sum, itertools.product(*m))

print(list(res))
```

Comment: Consider adding `list` for Python3.x - eg. print(list(res)) ?